# SSRS tooltips not appearing in deployed reports for some users

Tags: charts, reporting-services, tooltip

I've created an SSRS report using Visual Studio.  The report has several charts.  I've set up tooltips on the chart segments, for example a bar chart displays a tooltip when the user's mouse hovers over any bar in the chart.  The tooltips are defined by expressions and they work: I can see the tooltips in the VS preview environment and also when I open the deployed report on the report server.  At least one other user can also see the tooltips in the deployed report.  However, some users don't see any tooltips; they can view the deployed report, but they don't get any tooltips regardless of where they hover the mouse over the chart.  Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: Charts are ultimately rendered as an HTML `<img>` and then a `<map>` and `<area>`s for the tooltips. My first guess without any additional info would be it has something to do with some difference in the users' browser and/or possibly resolution compared to yours (could be some sort of issue with the coordinates maybe if their resolution is vastly different than yours? Shot in the dark maybe).

Comment: I was finally able to visit a few users in person.  It turns out that they're an impatient bunch: the tooltips do eventually appear but the wait time is somewhat longer than normal.  I'm thinking of just deleting this question because it's a Red Herring.